# sed replace word after a character

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to find in a file all word follow by slash '/' and replace them by empty

Example:

```
I/a want/s to/as remove/po word/sa after/al slash/q ./.
-> I want to remove word after slash .
```

I thought about this command but it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/(\/\w+)/g' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
```

Does any one have a suggestion ? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Both the solutions of Yudong and Choroba work well, thank you.

For more general, I think about finding characters after slash until reaching a space with the pattern:

```
\/[^ ]+
```

But it doesn't work in `sed 's/\/[^\ ]+//g'`

Does any one help me to explain it ?

Comment: The syntax is `s/old/new/g`. You're missing the `new` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'I/a want/s to/as remove/po word/sa after/al slash/q ./.' | sed 's/\/[a-zA-Z.]*//g'
I want to remove word after slash .
```

`'s/(\/\w+)/g'` you missed a replace section, sed replace should be like: `sed 's/regexp/replacement/'` .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\B` boundary, it matches inside "words":

```
sed 's=/\(.\B\)*.==g'
```

Note that I used `=` as the delimiters to avoid the need to backslash the slash.

Comment: Imo using `=` for the separator is a bit confusing.